# How to get gwt widget default stylename

Tags: css, gwt

In gwt how to get a widget's default style(CSS Selector).For example, gwt button has style name "gwt-button" which is referenced in gwt theme css file. 
How to got that programmatically.
Is there any,

DOM.getStyleAttribute();

to accomplish this. GWT experts please help.

Answer (score 2):

In your example of button (or any object that is a child of UIObject) can call getStyleName()

[UIObject documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html)

```
String com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject.getStyleName()


Gets all of the object's style names, as a space-separated list. If you wish to retrieve only the primary style name, call getStylePrimaryName().
```

Now as to why you need this information is the real question. It is my guess that you want to change the styling of an object (add or remove). This would best be done by either of the following methods.

1) Supplying a custom resources file to the object that has your styling

2) creating a class that extends Composite and create a custom UIBinder class with all of your styles within it.

Comment: Or, (3) modifying default values in your CSS file; (4) adding a new style defined in your CSS file.

Comment: This is true as well. When adding a new style to the CSS it will not override the default styling (if one exists) without adding the !important; flag after your style.  For example if you want to override the buttons color in the css file directly and add that style the parser will add your style first then the gwt. Thus the gwt will override yours. Adding the !important; flag to you styles background styling will push its priority to top.